# Insert string into mysql multiple times, removing last character each time, with one query

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

Using MySQL, I'm looking to write a single insert query that will take a single string and insert it multiple times, each time removing the last character.

So the query would be something like

```
INSERT INTO table (str) VALUES ("string") .....
```

and would result in the following values being inserted

```
string
strin
stri
str
st
s
```

I could do this PHP, but I'm wondering if there is an SQL solution first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to write a stored procedure and then just call it to do the inserts.

```
DELIMITER #

CREATE PROCEDURE 'insert_string_rows' (IN 'str' text)

BEGIN

DECLARE len int unsigned;
SET len = CHAR_LENGTH(str);

WHILE len > 0 DO
    INSERT INTO table VALUES (str);
    SET str = SUBSTR(str, 1, len - 1);
    SET len = CHAR_LENGTH(str);
END WHILE;

END#

DELIMITER ;
```

Then just simply

```
CALL insert_string_rows ("string")
```

and out pops all the rows into 'table'

```
string
strin
stri
str
st
s
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table of numbers, you could do:

```
insert into table(str)
    select left(@str, n.n)
    from (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
          select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
         ) n
    where length(@str) >= n.n
    order by n.n desc;
```

Comment: Very nice ... if the OP wants them inserted in order, you'll want to put an `ORDER BY n.n` at the end. Also, I think the `WHERE` clause should be `WHERE length(@str) >= n.n` - see similar SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0e55/6

Answer (score 1):

This approach requires that you create another table and prepopulate it with numbers, but it's easy to do and makes sense if this is something you will have to do repeatedly. I just tested this in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1be99/8)

```
create table table1 (string1 varchar(10));
create table table2 (number1 integer);

insert into table2 values (1);
insert into table2 values (2);
insert into table2 values (3);
insert into table2 values (4);
insert into table2 values (5);
insert into table2 values (6);
insert into table2 values (7);
insert into table2 values (8);
insert into table2 values (9);
insert into table2 values (10);

insert into table1 (string1)
select left(stringval, number1) 
from (select 'ninechars' as stringval ) as a
join table2 on table2.number1 <= char_length(a.stringval)

select * from table1

STRING1
n
ni
nin
nine
ninec
ninech
ninecha
ninechar
ninechars
```

Of course, table2 in this case must have enough rows for the max length of the string you need to insert.